# child process window not appearing

Tags: c#, child-process

I am trying to create a child process from a c# console app that shows the console.  I tried the following but no window appeared.

```
        ProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(name)
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized,
            CreateNoWindow = false,
            ErrorDialog = false
        };

        if (args != null)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo.Arguments = args;
        }

        if (workingDirectory != null)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
        }

        Process = new Process {EnableRaisingEvents = true, StartInfo = ProcessStartInfo};
        Process.Start();
```

Comment: What is the value of `name`, `args` and `workingDirectory`?

Comment: The name is the name of the child console app (MyApp.exe)  for this discussion both the args an working workingDirectory are null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to run child process in the parent’s console is to setup `UseShellExecute` property of `ProcessStartInfo` class. Let’s consider an example that executes time command. Why time? Because it reads from standard input. This way you will know which console it uses.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            Arguments = "/c time"
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Starting child process...");
        using (var process = Process.Start(processInfo))
        {
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
}
```

We left the default value of `UseShellExecute`, which is `true`. It means that a shell will be used for the child process. Using shell means that a new console will be created.

Let’s flip the value of `UseShellExecute` to `false`.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            UseShellExecute = false, // change value to false
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            Arguments = "/c time"
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Starting child process...");
        using (var process = Process.Start(processInfo))
        {
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: with as few changes to remove the Redirecting of the output I got the window to appear.  thanks for the assistance